# MySQL query failing due to reserved keyword?

Tags: php, mysql, database

**Edit: If you're coming here from Google, this issue is a result of the word `int` being a reserved keyword in PHP.** See the end of the accepted answer.

I'm still learning PHP/MySQL and for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

I'm trying to take some data from an html page and add it to a table in my database. I'm passing the data with a `GET` request, then retrieving it with PHP's `$_GET`.

I've tested this and the variables are passed correctly to the PHP script but they don't appear in the database. The script dies on this line:
`mysql_query($query) or die('data entry failed');`

```
$database='a9293297_blog';
$con = mysql_connect('mysql2.000webhost.com','my_username','my_password');
mysql_select_db($database,$con) or die('failed to connect to database');

$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$charName = $_GET['charName'];
$sex = $_GET['sex'];
$class = $_GET['class'];
$race = $_GET['race'];
$str = $_GET['str'];
$sta = $_GET['sta'];
$dex = $_GET['dex'];
$int = $_GET['int'];
$cha = $_GET['cha'];

$query = "INSERT INTO Players (username, password, charName, sex, class, race, str, sta, dex, int, cha)
VALUES ('" . $username . "', '" . $password . "', '" . $charName . "', '" . $sex . "', '" . $class . "', '" . $race . "', '" . $str . "', '" . $sta ."', '" . $dex . "', '" . $int . "', '". $cha . "')";

mysql_query($query) or die('data entry failed'); // Fails here
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Does it output anything?

Comment: Are you sure that the $query variable is being populated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To know better what's wrong with your SQL query, use **[mysql_error()](http://fr.php.net/mysql_error)**:

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Escape your string variables with **[mysql_real_escape_string()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)**. Example:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE(MYFIELD) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($myVar)."');
```

**EDIT**

`int` seems to be a reserved MySQL keyword. Escape it with backquotes:

```
INSERT INTO Players (username, password, ..., str, sta, dex, `int`, cha) ...
```

Comment: now it gives me this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int, cha)

Comment: Thank you, I never would have figured that out! Everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure but try this

Your Code

```
$query="INSERT INTO Players (username, password, charName, sex, class, race, str, sta, dex, int, cha)VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$charName."', '".$sex."', '".$class."', '".$race."', '".$str."', '".$sta."', '".$dex."', '".$int."', '".$cha."')";
```

In this code

```
$query="INSERT INTO Players (username, password, charName, sex, class, race, str, sta, dex, int, cha)VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$charName', '$sex', '$class', '$race', '$str', '$sta', '$dex', '$int', '$cha')";
```

Maybe this helps if you remove " and .

Comment: thanks, that's what I tried originally. But putting the variables in quotes treats them as strings...